# SELECT WITH LIKE AND WHERE QUERY in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am having issues of selecting a query with a condition in PHP

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(v_name, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_name,
       AES_DECRYPT(v_email, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_email,
       AES_DECRYPT(v_id_no, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_id_no,
       AES_DECRYPT(v_phone, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_phone,
       v_id, c_id, v_purpose
FROM visitor
WHERE c_id = '1' AND
      AES_DECRYPT(v_name, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
      AES_DECRYPT(v_email, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
      AES_DECRYPT(v_id_no, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
      AES_DECRYPT(v_phone, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
      v_purpose LIKE '%a%'
```

[I am trying to query search with 'a' but using c_id = 1, but these are the actual results im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKSD5.png)

[I need to be querying viewingthese results instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHD9o.png)

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: You need to put ORs in parentheses. The AND is only connecting the first two conditions now

Comment: Awesome! It worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need parentheses in the right places.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(v_name, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_name, AES_DECRYPT(v_email, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_email,
       AES_DECRYPT(v_id_no, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_id_no, AES_DECRYPT(v_phone, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') as v_phone,
       v_id, c_id, v_purpose
FROM visitor
WHERE c_id = '1' AND
      (AES_DECRYPT(v_name, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
       AES_DECRYPT(v_email, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
       AES_DECRYPT(v_id_no, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
       AES_DECRYPT(v_phone, 'k7ewjks93ls82!!') LIKE '%a%' OR
       v_purpose LIKE '%a%'
      );
```

(Note:  I'm not sure if `v_purpose` should be in the `OR` logic.)

If you are learning SQL/programming, then use parentheses whenever you mix `AND` and `OR` operators.  That will prevent such problems in the future.